# Command Failed:gradlew.bat app:installRelease -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

Whenever I try to build release apk with this command `npx react-native run-android --variant=release` I'm getting error mentioned above.  I was building apk last night and it was taking too much time so i cancelled it. this error started coming after that. `1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details` which never came before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions of what to do:

- The classic `cd android`, `./gradlew clean` and then `./gradlew assembleRelease`;
- Verify if `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` is included in
  `release { buildTypes {}}`  at app\build.gradle;
- run `npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` and then `npx react-native run-android --variant=release`.

Comment: @AqsaMaan if my answer was helpful, please help me by giving the up vote